# Discrete Ergodic spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, ergodic-theory, eigenfunctions

> $\textbf{Problem}$ An ergodic measure preserving transformation $T$ on $(X,B,\mu)$ is called to have ${discrete \ spectrum}$ if there exists an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ which consists of eigenfunctions of $T$. Show that there is a sequence of integers $n_k$ with $n_k \rightarrow \infty$ such that for any $f \in L^2$, 
>   \begin{align*}
> \Vert T^{n_k}f - f \Vert _{L^2} \rightarrow 0
> \end{align*}

$\textbf{Attempt}$ We know that for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\vert \lambda \vert =1$, there is $n_k$ such that $\lambda^{n_k} \rightarrow 1$.

Suppose that $\{f_1,f_2,...,\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $L^2$ which consists of eigenfunctions of $T$.

Then, $T f_i = \lambda_i f_i $ and $\vert \lambda_i \vert =1$. Moreover, for each $i$, there exists $\{i_j\}_{j=1}$ such that $\lambda_i^{i_j} \rightarrow 1$.

(*) Then, by using a diagonal argument, there is a sequence of integers $n_k$ such that for any $f \in L^2$,
\begin{align*}
T^{n_k}f = \lambda ^{n_k} f \rightarrow f 
\end{align*}
as $n_k \rightarrow \infty$.

I am not sure whether (*) is correct or not.

Any help is appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: Everything up to the diagonal argument looks fine. But note that not all $f \in L^2$ is an eigenfunction of $T$. So you may want to argue by expanding $f = \sum_i a_i f_i$ and then writing $$\|T^n f - f\|_{L^2}^2 = \sum_i |a_i|^2 |1 - \lambda_i^n|^2. $$ Along the subsequence $n = n_k$, this converges to $0$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'diagonal' argument is correct. To complete the proof you can use the following: $\|T^{n_k}f-f\| \leq \|T^{n_k}g-g\|+\|T^{n_k}f-T^{n_k}g\|+\|f-g\| \leq \|T^{n_k}g-g\|++2\|f-g\|$ becasue $T$ is measure preserving. In view of this it is enough to prove that  $T^{n_k}f-f \to 0$ when $f$ is a finite linear combination of eigen functions. (Any $f \in L^{2}$ has an $L^{2}$ expansion of the type $\sum a_j f_j$). Of course, convergence does hold for finite linear combination s of $f_j$'s, so we are done.

Comment: What is your g???

Comment: I have stated the inequality for ant $f$ and $g$. To apply this you first approximate $f$ by a $g$ which is a finite linear combination of $f_j$'s. You make $\|f-g\|<\epsilon$ and then use that fact that $\|T^{n_k}g-g\| \to 0$.